# how to keep getting "accelerometer:didAccelerate:" when app in background

Tags: iphone, background, accelerometer

How can my app keep getting a call to its "accelerometer:didAccelerate:" method of UIAccelerometerDelegate IF another app interrupts my app, such as the iPhone user receiving a phone call?

My app measures motion, but stops if suspended by the user, or if interrupted by another app.

I know this has been difficult in the past, but maybe there is something new in iOS.

Thanks!

Comment: See answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716466/how-nike-gps-on-iphone-receives-accelerometer-updates-in-the-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, apple standards are to block the app when a proccess pops in, It freezes the app at the moment it was interrupted. If finishes the last proccess it started in the background then it freezes the app. If you find a way around it i'd love to know it. Here is something that might help you to find the solution [stackoverflow post similar to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762200/how-to-keep-an-iphone-app-running-on-background-fully-operational)