# Acceleration in a for..... loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

I have a for....loop and the UI then is blocked when in the loop.
Is the accelerometer also blocked?

I have following code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
 }
```

and further down

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    acc=acceleration.x;
}
```

then an IBAction connected to a button which starts a loop

```
- (IBAction)doSomething {
    for (int n = 1; n<=100;n++) {
        // do someting in the loop
        NSLog(@"x: %g", acc);
     }
 }
```

when logging the accelerometer x value it shows only the first value when the button is pressed and does not update when the loop is running. The same first value is repeating continuously.
Is there a way to log the acceleration when in the loop?

Comment: Your update interval is 1/60th of a second. I'm pretty sure an iPhone or a Simulator can complete 100 iterations of a for-loop in less time than that?

Comment: And i guess it is deprecated delegate in ios5+

Comment: Yes, that I know, but it was just an example, let say n is infinit then

Comment: May be it is deprecated but it sure works in my Phone which runs iOS6 but the case was if it is possible to get the acc when UI is blocked

Comment: I am not sure but can you check with multiple threads?

Comment: @Lars - sounds like you are proposing an infinite loop on the main thread.  The common approach is to sample on a repeating timer.

Comment: First, what the loop does take at least 5 seconds for every loop. And my approach first is now to try a multiple thread. And also I will try a timer. Could very well work because I now have a sleep function in the loop to get some delay and that the timer will solve as well. Will be back with the result in some days.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that UIAccelerometer needs the main thread so is getting blocked by the for...loop. Core Motion also has an accelerometer property in the `CMMotionManager` object that can report acceleration, and does better backgrounding since it's what Nike+ uses. There are two ways to access it - a pull method where you get the data directly, or a call-back. To be honest, I just tried it and couldn't get the call-back to work (mostly because it requires NSOperationQueue and I don't have much experience with that so I'm probably putting it on the wrong queue), but if you're ok with pulling data, which your approach seems to need, then this works:

```
CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Acceleration: %f", motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x);
}
```

I just tried it on a device and the values reported in the for...loop update with the current acceleration.

Source: [UIBackgroundModes and UIAccelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351961/uibackgroundmodes-and-uiaccelerometer)

Comment: Not that any kind of a polling for() loop should be considered a serious bug and you should strive to eliminate it.  **Never never never** block the main event loop and, in general, never block a queue or a runloop.

Comment: Yeah not exactly a great way to do it but figured this question/method was an abstraction of some other method of implementation.

Comment: if this works it is perfect. Thanks, will be back soon with my result

Comment: @Lars- - did this end up working for you? Let me know, and please accept the answer if it did.

Comment: Thank you for this.  This solved my problem while using cocos2d-xna and monogame.  My accelerometer data was stale and delayed real values when I was getting them updated by a delegate.  Now by polling the values are correct, and can continue on my way.  

This answer should be accepted as correct.