# Getting accelerometer data in background using CoreMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I'm unable to receive accelerometer data in the background, despite the seemingly correct solution per this question [How Nike+ GPS on iPhone receives accelerometer updates in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716466/how-nike-gps-on-iphone-receives-accelerometer-updates-in-the-background)

```
[_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                         withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 NSLog(@"perform");
                                                 [(id) self setAcceleration:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                             });}];
```

perform is logged whenever the app is in the foreground, but whenever I exit out to background it stops running. Does anyone have any idea why this might be? I've checked "Location Updates" in Background Modes...

Comment: I've noticed it seems to work in the background if you use [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] instead of create a new queue.

Answer (score 7):

Put this code right in front of that line (after making a member variable called bgTaskID of type UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier):

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        __weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;
        self.bgTaskID = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            __strong __typeof(&*weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

            NSLog(@"BG TASK EXPIRED!");

            if (strongSelf) {
                [application endBackgroundTask:strongSelf.bgTaskID];
                strongSelf.bgTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Works fine for iOS 7 for me. Did you mean iOS 8?

Comment: NO I mean IOS 7.
I need the coreMotion Information, does this solution also works with Automotive/running/walking Information of the CoreMotion Processor in background? Is it also possible to start e.g. gps to get locations based on that information?

Comment: it works for core motion. You can also use it to get GPS information.

Comment: You are brilliant!  Works great in iOS 9.3.  Solved a big problem for me

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using CoreMotion framework. You have to import CoreMotion framework, then `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>` in your `appdelegate`.

Here motionManager is object of `CMMotionManager`.

`xData, yData, zData` are double values to store accelerometer data.

```
if (motionManager ==nil) {
    motionManager= [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
}
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
    xData = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
    yData = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
    zData = accelerometerData.acceleration.z;
}];
```

You have to do it in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

You can then use these value of `xData, yData, zData` where ever you want by `appdelegate` object, even in background.