# pick the sensors (accelerometer, gyroscope) data while the iPhone locked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sensors

the main idea of an app i'm working on it is: if the user picked up and put down his iPhone even if it's locked; or interact with it(i.e press the home button, volume button, power button), i should inform the app to do something.
the big problem that faced me is the sensors don't work in the background, and i saw a problem like mine here with no answer: 
[iOS 7.1: Get Core Motion data (accelerometer, gyroscope) while app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459684/ios-7-1-get-core-motion-data-accelerometer-gyroscope-while-app-is-in-backgro/28385741#28385741)

so please anyone can help me with this mission? any example ?
I'd be thankful for any help.