# Need to run the app when unlock the device

Tags: iphone, unlock, system-configuration

I'm trying to do an app which runs when user unlock(Slide to unlock) their device.  I don't know anything how to approach for this app.   Please any one could help me?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Without [jailbreaking](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) there is no official way to get this kind of behavior. The user has to launch the application to start the application. The best you can do is try to [keep your application alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762200/how-to-keep-an-iphone-app-running-on-background-fully-operational) in the background by playing a silent sound (wastes battery) or setting a timeout which I believe Apple currently limits to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to your question is really is. If you want your app on the AppStore, there's no way. 
On an iPhone the user always decides when an app runs. Sorry you can't these things.

Of course there are possibilites but you need to jailbreak your iPhone. And with this way, your application will **not** be accepted on the AppStore.

Sandro Meier

Comment: Thank you Meier,  I know that apple will reject these kind of apps.  But I want to do this app for jailbroken devices and that too I want to keep this app in cydia. So please suggest me how to do this.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. But sorry, I'm the wrong one for this. So far I only created AppStore Applications.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should read [App Store Review Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf) and you will have your answer.