# iOS App running in Background

Tags: ios, background

I have an app that need to poll the status from the server in a regular time interval (1 minute), to trigger alarm in the app.

to keep the app active in background for this purpose. I am thinking to enable the Location Updates for the background mode. So I can still continue to poll data from the server.

Is this feasible ? or will my app get rejected by Apple ?

or , there is better way of keeping app alive in background to allow me poll data at 1 minute interval ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep an iPhone app running on background fully operational](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762200/how-to-keep-an-iphone-app-running-on-background-fully-operational)

Answer (score 6):

Apple does not allow apps to run in the background. If you want to trigger an alarm remotely, you should use [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apple wont allow to run the application in background.The app will get rejected for this.
Apple automatically deactive the application after few hours.

You can use APNS notification for this