# NStimer stopped at middle

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am doing one application.In that,i am calling one method for every 10 seconds using the timer.But after sometime that method is not calling. So,may i know the reason for why timer is stopped.

Comment: share some code.

Comment: Just started the timer  myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(recordFile1:) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25658491/2522457 -- plz check this.

Comment: after somtimes means how much time ?

Comment: is your timer works on background ?

Comment: In foreground only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a ScrollView scrolling, the timer in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` will be stopped.

You can use this to fix it:
`[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking Timer in Foreground and background, Timer will work continuously in foreground, But in background it will work only 10 mins, After that timer will not work.