# How to run app that needs bluetooth in background for forever?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I have an app that uses Bluetooth to connect with a Bluetooth device that gives a temperature reading. When the temperature reaches a certain level the alarm rings. It works perfectly fine in the foreground.
The problem is I am not being able to get data from a device while it's in the background. Since the nature of the app is it must connect with Bluetooth devices and get data all the time. How can I run this kind of app in the background forever?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762200/how-to-keep-an-iphone-app-running-on-background-fully-operational

Answer (score 1):

Have you requested the `bluetooth-central` background mode?

See the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) for more:

> If your app needs to run in background to perform certain Bluetooth-related tasks, it must declare that it supports a Core Bluetooth background execution mode in its Information property list (Info.plist) file. When your app declares this, the system wakes it up from a suspended state to allow it to handle Bluetooth-related events. This support is important for apps that interact with Bluetooth low energy devices that deliver data at regular intervals, such as a heart rate monitor.

Comment: In which situations app gets relaunched again. What if app is killed by user. Will it relaunched again in background.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it's killed by the user, it will not get relaunched again.